# Content Security Policy Wildcards?

Tags: javascript, security, content-security-policy, react-helmet

I'm getting this content security policy error:

> Refused to connect to 'https://web-2.statscollector.sd-rtn.com:6443/events/proto-raws' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src [.....]

My content security policy rules for connect-src include:

```
"https://*.statscollector.sd-rtn.com:6443/*",
```

Am I not using wildcards correctly?

Comment: Just try this ```https://*.statscollector.sd-rtn.com:6443``` as your content security rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just have to provide the domain and should not include the path of the domain.

Valid wildcard host names expressions include `"*.google.com"` and `"*"`.

Invalid wildcard host name expressions include `"www.*.com"`, `"*.google.*"` and `"google.*"`.

Reference for it:- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CSP/Specification#Hostname_Wildcards

Just try to use like this `https://*.statscollector.sd-rtn.com:6443` as your content security rule

Comment: Is it okay to include a second wildcard after a colon for the port number, e.g. `https://*.agoraio.cn:*/"` ?

Comment: yeah! we can use it like this too incase of dynamic port number